# How do I create a "floating" widget/block?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, widget

I'm trying to create a floating widget/block that can sit over on the left of my website like the attached picture. I want to advertise my catalogue for download.[image]

Comment: Create Static block for ads & use this block through widget also you need to add custom css & js file into your used theme.

Comment: @MagikVishal you should post this as the answer as this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will see if I can get a developer to do this for me. Thanks again